# Is is good practice to create new contract address for each transaction?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

Is it good practice to create new contract address when there is new data and execute the transaction, or create on single contract instance address which has a mapping variable  and data can be added into it. Either cases which is good option for data retrieval?

For Example -  I've seen web3js where they create a new instance of the contract on the blockchain and store the data in its variables and later fetch the data based on the contract address. So its like creating multiple objects to store single record although a contract instance can store multiple. On the Flip side there are web3js code where only one contract instance is created and store the data in a mapping variable.

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is unclear

Comment: @gaiazov - Updated the Question with example

Answer (score 1):

If you can it is better to store a mapping inside 1 contract. Because contract creation is rather expensive in terms of gas. Besides that you also need to track the newly created contracts.